# Using Html Id in ExtJS4

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am new to ExtJS4.May i know how to get html Id in ExtJS4.If you have a sample please share with me.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to get html Id of

Comment: I need to use the html id in ExtJS4 page.For Example,               <div id="example_div"/>.I need to use this id in ExtJS4.

Comment: In `ExtJS` it's very uncommon to use id. Perhaps there is better way to do it? Just my 2cents

Answer (score 1):

In ExtJS4 you can get dom node by it's id using:

```
Ext.DomQuery.selectNode('#example_div');
```

or using oldschool js:

```
document.getElementById('example_div');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
var elDom = Ext.getDom('example_div');
```

I have not used it but found it in the docs.